# MVP Passive View - Composite Views & Composite Presenters

Tags: java, swing, mvp, passive-view

I found M. Fowler article on [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) pattern. I would like to apply it in my application. I use Swing for UI. I spent several hours searching tutorials or examples how to implement it but not much useful found. Could anybody help to understand the design or provide good examples here? By "M" in MVP I understand "Domain Model".

Answer (score 2):

**MVP = Model View Presenter**

The basic idea is, that you separate presenting logic from UI (view), so you can mock out the view and test presenter with simple JUnit tests, instead of messing the swing (probably generated by designer) code with your "view logic" (code that controls the UI)...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM

Really nice presentation by Ray Ryan. He talks about GWT, but the idea of MVP is well explained...

MVP starts at 21:30

Answer (score 1):

MVP can be explained the following way:

Model -- the domain model of your application. All business logic is here.

Presenter -- All view logic is here. Retrieves data from model and updates the view.

View -- UI presentation. Contains no updating logic. Fires events to the presenter on user interaction something and listens to the events from the presenter.